# Ubuntu 19.10 randomly losing WiFi connection

Tags: networking, wireless

WiFi network randomly disconnects, sometimes after few hours, sometimes every one minute. When it happends I have to reconnect manually and this is very frustrating.

Looks like it is associated with DNS, because the last thing before it happends is that line in journalctl:

```
systemd-resolved[958]: Using degraded feature set (TCP) for DNS server 8.8.8.8.
```

Icon shows that I'm still connected to my network, but if I try to open any page (both local like 192.168.0.1 or global) browser says: Connecting to host and after few seconds I'm getting connection error.

Output of:

```
lshw -c network
```

Looks like this:

```
description: Wireless interface
product: QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
physical id: 0
bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
logical name: wlp3s0
version: 31
serial: 40:23:43:0a:da:e5
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=4.15.0-1067-oem firmware=WLAN.TF.2.1-00021-QCARMSWP-1 ip=192.168.0.59 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
resources: irq:139 memory:c1000000-c11fffff
```

Content of /etc/resolve.conf file:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
nameserver 62.179.1.60
# Too many DNS servers configured, the following entries may be ignored.
nameserver 62.179.1.61
search home
```

More journalctl logs:

> lut 15 18:13:22  wicd[988]: Throttling autoreconnect lut 15 18:13:22 
>   wicd[988]: Starting automatic reconnect process lut 15 18:13:22 
>   wicd[988]: Throttling autoreconnect lut 15 18:13:22  wicd[988]:
>   Starting automatic reconnect process lut 15 18:13:22  wicd[988]:
>   Throttling autoreconnect lut 15 18:13:22  wicd[988]: Throttling
>   autoreconnect lut 15 18:13:22  wicd[988]: Starting automatic reconnect
>   process lut 15 18:13:22  wicd[988]: Throttling autoreconnect lut 15
>   18:13:22  wicd[988]: Starting automatic reconnect process lut 15
>   18:13:22  wicd[988]: Throttling autoreconnect lut 15 18:14:13 
>   xdg-desktop-por[2290]: Failed to get application states:
>   GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.portal.Error.Failed: Could not get window
>   list: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: App
>   introspection not allowed lut 15 18:15:01  CRON[22366]:
>   pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0) lut 15
>   18:15:01  CRON[22367]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null
>   && debian-sa1 1 1) lut 15 18:15:01  CRON[22366]:
>   pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root lut 15 18:15:13 
>   xdg-desktop-por[2290]: Failed to get application states:
>   GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.portal.Error.Failed: Could not get window
>   list: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: App
>   introspection not allowed lut 15 18:16:13  xdg-desktop-por[2290]:
>   Failed to get application states:
>   GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.portal.Error.Failed: Could not get window
>   list: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: App
>   introspection not allowed lut 15 18:16:38  systemd-resolved[958]:
>   Using degraded feature set (UDP) for DNS server 8.8.8.8. lut 15
>   18:16:47  systemd-resolved[958]: Using degraded feature set (UDP) for
>   DNS server 8.8.4.4. lut 15 18:16:50  systemd-resolved[958]: Failed to
>   send hostname reply: Invalid argument lut 15 18:16:50 
>   systemd-resolved[958]: Failed to send hostname reply: Invalid argument
>   lut 15 18:16:50  systemd-resolved[958]: Failed to send hostname reply:
>   Invalid argument lut 15 18:16:50  systemd-resolved[958]: Failed to
>   send hostname reply: Invalid argument lut 15 18:16:50 
>   systemd-resolved[958]: Failed to send hostname reply: Invalid argument
>   lut 15 18:16:50  systemd-resolved[958]: Failed to send hostname reply:
>   Invalid argument lut 15 18:16:55  systemd-resolved[958]: Using
>   degraded feature set (TCP) for DNS server 8.8.8.8. lut 15 18:17:00 
>   systemd-resolved[958]: Using degraded feature set (TCP) for DNS server
>   8.8.4.4. lut 15 18:17:01  CRON[22455]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0) lut 15 18:17:01  CRON[22456]: (root)
>   CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly) lut 15 18:17:01 
>   CRON[22455]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root lut
>   15 18:17:13  xdg-desktop-por[2290]: Failed to get application states:
>   GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.portal.Error.Failed: Could not get window
>   list: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: App
>   introspection not allowed lut 15 18:17:32  systemd-resolved[958]:
>   Using degraded feature set (UDP) for DNS server 8.8.8.8. lut 15
>   18:17:36  NetworkManager[1026]:   [1581787056.3669] dhcp4
>   (wlp3s0): state changed bound -> bound lut 15 18:17:36 
>   dbus-daemon[1006]: [system] Activating via systemd: service
>   name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
>   unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.24'
>   (uid=0 pid=1026 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon "
>   label="unconfined") lut 15 18:17:36  systemd[1]: Starting Network
>   Manager Script Dispatcher Service... lut 15 18:17:36 
>   dbus-daemon[1006]: [system] Successfully activated service
>   'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' lut 15 18:17:36  systemd[1]: Started
>   Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service. lut 15 18:17:36 
>   nm-dispatcher[22520]: Error: missing function library
>   \'/usr/share/tlp/tlp-functions\'. lut 15 18:17:36 
>   nm-dispatcher[22520]: req:1 'dhcp4-change' [wlp3s0],
>   "/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/99tlp-rdw-nm": complete: failed with
>   Script '/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/99tlp-rdw-nm' exited with
>   error status 1. lut 15 18:17:36  NetworkManager[1026]:  
>   [1581787056.4053] dispatcher: (595)
>   /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/99tlp-rdw-nm failed (failed): Script
>   '/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/99tlp-rdw-nm' exited with error
>   status 1. lut 15 18:17:46  systemd[1]:
>   NetworkManager-dispatcher.service: Succeeded. lut 15 18:17:49 
>   systemd-resolved[958]: Using degraded feature set (TCP) for DNS server
>   8.8.8.8. lut 15 18:18:06  systemd-resolved[958]: Using degraded feature set (UDP) for DNS server 8.8.4.4. lut 15 18:18:13 
>   xdg-desktop-por[2290]: Failed to get application states:
>   GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.portal.Error.Failed: Could not get window
>   list: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: App
>   introspection not allowed lut 15 18:18:15  systemd-resolved[958]:
>   Using degraded feature set (TCP) for DNS server 8.8.4.4. lut 15
>   18:18:30  guake.desktop[2579]: Showing the terminal lut 15 18:18:32 
>   systemd-resolved[958]: Using degraded feature set (UDP) for DNS server
>   8.8.8.8. lut 15 18:18:48  systemd-resolved[958]: Using degraded feature set (TCP) for DNS server 8.8.8.8. lut 15 18:18:50 
>   systemd-resolved[958]: Failed to send hostname reply: Invalid argument
>   lut 15 18:19:00  systemd-resolved[958]: Using degraded feature set
>   (UDP) for DNS server 8.8.4.4. lut 15 18:19:13  xdg-desktop-por[2290]:
>   Failed to get application states:
>   GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.portal.Error.Failed: Could not get window
>   list: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: App
>   introspection not allowed lut 15 18:19:17  systemd-resolved[958]:
>   Using degraded feature set (UDP) for DNS server 8.8.8.8. lut 15
>   18:19:20  systemd-resolved[958]: Using degraded feature set (TCP) for
>   DNS server 8.8.4.4. lut 15 18:19:20  systemd-resolved[958]: Failed to
>   send hostname reply: Invalid argument lut 15 18:19:25 
>   systemd-resolved[958]: Using degraded feature set (TCP) for DNS server
>   8.8.8.8. lut 15 18:19:35  systemd-resolved[958]: Using degraded feature set (UDP) for DNS server 8.8.4.4.

And some last logs from dmesg:

> wlp3s0: deauthenticating from 90:5c:44:72:a1:13 by local choice
>   (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING) [355659.518343] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0:
>   failed to flush transmit queue (skip 0 ar-state 1): 0 [355659.541221]
>   IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp3s0: link is not ready [355669.457871]
>   wlp3s0: authenticate with 90:5c:44:72:a1:13 [355669.487781] wlp3s0:
>   send auth to 90:5c:44:72:a1:13 (try 1/3) [355669.508416] wlp3s0:
>   authenticated [355669.510195] wlp3s0: associate with 90:5c:44:72:a1:13
>   (try 1/3) [355669.546795] wlp3s0: RX AssocResp from 90:5c:44:72:a1:13
>   (capab=0x1511 status=0 aid=5) [355669.550761] wlp3s0: associated
>   [355669.579313] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp3s0: link becomes
>   ready [356083.462491] wlp3s0: deauthenticating from 90:5c:44:72:a1:13
>   by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING) [356088.572038] ath10k_pci
>   0000:03:00.0: failed to flush transmit queue (skip 0 ar-state 1): 0
>   [356088.588795] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp3s0: link is not ready
>   [356088.699158] wlp3s0: authenticate with 90:5c:44:72:a1:13
>   [356088.732123] wlp3s0: send auth to 90:5c:44:72:a1:13 (try 1/3)
>   [356090.203946] wlp3s0: send auth to 90:5c:44:72:a1:13 (try 2/3)
>   [356090.754413] wlp3s0: authenticated [356090.756002] wlp3s0:
>   associate with 90:5c:44:72:a1:13 (try 1/3) [356090.792744] wlp3s0: RX
>   AssocResp from 90:5c:44:72:a1:13 (capab=0x1511 status=0 aid=5)
>   [356090.796234] wlp3s0: associated [356090.825418] IPv6:
>   ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp3s0: link becomes ready [358464.027449]
>   wlp3s0: deauthenticating from 90:5c:44:72:a1:13 by local choice
>   (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING) [358469.106513] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0:
>   failed to flush transmit queue (skip 0 ar-state 1): 0 [358469.118493]
>   IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp3s0: link is not ready [358479.059319]
>   wlp3s0: authenticate with 90:5c:44:72:a1:13 [358479.089699] wlp3s0:
>   send auth to 90:5c:44:72:a1:13 (try 1/3) [358479.110305] wlp3s0:
>   authenticated [358479.114497] wlp3s0: associate with 90:5c:44:72:a1:13
>   (try 1/3) [358479.151105] wlp3s0: RX AssocResp from 90:5c:44:72:a1:13
>   (capab=0x1511 status=0 aid=5) [358479.154207] wlp3s0: associated
>   [358479.183955] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp3s0: link becomes
>   ready [361631.673834] wlp3s0: deauthenticating from 90:5c:44:72:a1:13
>   by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING) [361635.912482] ath10k_pci
>   0000:03:00.0: Unknown eventid: 3 [361635.927682] ath10k_pci
>   0000:03:00.0: Unknown eventid: 118809 [361635.930723] ath10k_pci
>   0000:03:00.0: Unknown eventid: 90118 [361636.062381] IPv6:
>   ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp3s0: link is not ready [361640.973162] wlp3s0:
>   authenticate with 90:5c:44:72:a1:13 [361641.004030] wlp3s0: send auth
>   to 90:5c:44:72:a1:13 (try 1/3) [361641.025022] wlp3s0: authenticated
>   [361641.030274] wlp3s0: associate with 90:5c:44:72:a1:13 (try 1/3)
>   [361641.067193] wlp3s0: RX AssocResp from 90:5c:44:72:a1:13
>   (capab=0x1511 status=0 aid=5) [361641.071081] wlp3s0: associated
>   [361641.100672] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp3s0: link becomes
>   ready

Comment: Please post full `dmesg` and `journalctl` output, and your `/etc/resolvconf.conf`.

Comment: @FliegendeWurst Here you go. I've added some more details by editing my question.

Comment: Hello. Did youu resolve this issue?

Comment: @asgs Nope. I had to start to use wired connection.

Comment: That sucks. It is crazy. Keeps disconnecting every now and then. And restart seems to be the only workaround. And that too for a few min

Comment: I have the same problem. It is making me crazy. Here is my question https://askubuntu.com/questions/1362145/using-degraded-feature-set-tcp-instead-of-udp-for-dns-server-wifi-connection